# Securing APIs to check for user permissions - C# .Net

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, permissions, middleware

I want to wrap my APIs in some kind of middleware that will check if specific user has permission to access that API just like it's done in Golang.

For example: a user is logged in as a student in an educational application. This user knows the URL that will call an API and delete a grade specified by grade ID, however students don't have permissions to call any DELETE operation, only READ operations. I want to find a way to wrap that API in a way that even if the student is logged in, when they enter this URL and send the HTTP request, the application will first check for their permission (I am using Keycloack for authentication), and then based on their permissions go to the API or not.

I know how to do that in Golang but is that any simple way to that in a C# Web API Application?

Comment: There are more than one ways you can do this... You can issue an OAuth2 token to user when user logs in and the token has scope associated with it. For student user you assign only `read` scope to the token. When the API is called, the token must be passed in Authorization header. And the API should check if the token has appropriate scope for the API being called. And reject the request if the scope does not match. Such as any `delete` api requires `delete` scope in the token. If the token does not have `delete` scope then you reject the request.

Comment: @Chetan thanks for the reply! Let's say that I already have 20 APIs created without any authorization checking and now I want to start checking for this permissions. Isn't there any way to created a custom component that will wrap this APIs instead of manually hard code each one of this APIs to check for permissions?

Comment: @Chetan I know that you can easily do that in Golang with Middleware. The middleware will wrap the APIs and everytime they are called, the middleware will be called beforehand and do the whole checking. This is more dynamic and easy to do it. My idea was to created 4 middleware for each one of the CRUD operations and check if that user has permissions to do that operations in that specific table.

Comment: You can create your own AuthorizeFilter, which checks for authorization based on the API URL and the user which is calling the API. And use that filter on all the existing API controller actions.

Comment: @Chetan `AuthorizeFilter` Oh, that's it! That's what I need. Thank you so much!